# Magento2 : Error The "Is New" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

> When I try to save a new category, the result is the following error.
>   I'm using magento 2.3

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working solution:

Go to table "eav_attribute":
find line attribute code "is new" and edit:

1. mark "is required" to: 0
2. under "default value" text, uncheck the check box and set (write in) the field box: 0

Must work